# Cumulative count distinct in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, count, distinct

I need to count number of customers cumulatively for weeks. Is there any nice way to do that without making subqueries?

I've thied to look for some analytic functions but found nothing worthful. All the working solutions were using the subqueries or sum over count, which is wrong for my task.

For example, for these table

```
WITH the_data as (  
   select sysdate - 28 dt, 1 val from dual union all  
   select sysdate - 27 dt, 13 val from dual union all  
   select sysdate - 20 dt, 15 val from dual union all  
   select sysdate - 19 dt, 1 cusval from dual union all  
   select sysdate - 18 dt, 2  from dual union all  
   select sysdate - 17 dt, 3  from dual union all  
   select sysdate - 16 dt, 4  from dual union all  
   select sysdate - 15 dt, 5  from dual union all  
   select sysdate - 14 dt, 6  from dual union all  
   select sysdate - 8 dt, 7  from dual union all  
   select sysdate - 6 dt, 8  from dual union all  
   select sysdate - 3 dt, 9  from dual union all  
   select sysdate - 2 dt, 9  from dual union all  
   select sysdate - 1 dt, 10  from dual)
```

i want to get following

```
+----------------------------------+
| WEEK_NUM    CUM_DISTINCT_COUNT   |
+----------------------------------+
| 8           2                    |
| 9           6                    |
| 10          8                    |
| 11          11                   |
| 12          12                   |
+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: You should post your table structure, sample data, what you tried and the desired result; without these informations, it's quite impossible to answer. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you can read how to make a good question

Comment: Without any data it will be difficult to help you, however the solution could be like `COUNT(DISTINCT CUST_NUMBER) OVER (PARTITION BY WEEK)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       TRUNC( date_column, 'WW' ) AS week_number,
       COUNT( customer_id ) OVER ( ORDER BY TRUNC( date_column, 'WW' ) ) AS num_customers
FROM   your_table
ORDER BY week_number
```

To get the cumulative number of distinct customers since `2016-01-01` you could do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       last_day_of_week,
       COUNT( is_first_instance_of_customer )
         OVER( ORDER BY last_day_of_week ) AS num_unique_customers
FROM   (
  SELECT TRUNC( date_value, 'WW' ) + 6 AS last_day_of_week,
         CASE ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER ( PARTITION BY customer_id
                       ORDER BY date_value )
         WHEN 1
         THEN 1
         END AS is_first_instance_of_customer
  FROM   your_table
)
ORDER BY last_day_of_week;
```

Comment: Thank's, but that wouldn't work. That's how i get distinct pairs of week_number and num_customers. But i need number of customers between 01/01/2016 and final day of every week, plus my table "your_table" contains duplicates by customer_id

Comment: @Powerfool Updated with a cumulative count of distinct customers.

Answer (score 0):

How you do this depends on if your count needs to be of distinct customers or not. To show some running aggregate options:

```
WITH the_data as (
   select sysdate - 28 dt, 1 val from dual union all
   select sysdate - 27 dt, 13 val from dual union all
   select sysdate - 20 dt, 15 val from dual union all
   select sysdate - 19 dt, 1 cusval from dual union all
   select sysdate - 18 dt, 2  from dual union all
   select sysdate - 17 dt, 3  from dual union all
   select sysdate - 16 dt, 4  from dual union all
   select sysdate - 15 dt, 5  from dual union all
   select sysdate - 14 dt, 6  from dual union all
   select sysdate - 8 dt, 7  from dual union all
   select sysdate - 6 dt, 8  from dual union all
   select sysdate - 3 dt, 9  from dual union all
   select sysdate - 2 dt, 9  from dual union all
   select sysdate - 1 dt, 10  from dual)
select distinct trunc(dt,'WW') wk
      ,count(val) over (partition by trunc(dt,'WW')) as wk_cnt
      ,count(distinct val) over (partition by trunc(dt,'WW')) as wk_distinct_cnt
      ,count(val) over (order by trunc(dt,'WW')) as running_wk_cnt
--      ,count(distinct val) over (order by trunc(dt,'WW')) as running_distinct_wk_cnt
from the_data
order by trunc(dt,'WW')

returns
WK,         WK_CNT, WK_DISTINCT_CNT, RUNNING_WK_CNT
12/02/2016, 2,      2,               2
19/02/2016, 3,      3,               5
26/02/2016, 4,      4,               9
04/03/2016, 2,      2,               11
11/03/2016, 3,      2,               14
```

But if you uncomment the line to do a running distinct count you will get an error as that is not possible using exactly this construct.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody thanks. This is a working query i was asking for:

```
with dt as (  
select 'A1' PLANT, '1' CUSTOMERID, date'2016-01-01' CALDAY from dual union all
select 'A1' PLANT, '2' CUSTOMERID, date'2016-01-01' CALDAY from dual union all
select 'A1' PLANT, '3' CUSTOMERID, date'2016-01-01' CALDAY from dual union all
select 'A2' PLANT, '1' CUSTOMERID, date'2016-01-02' CALDAY from dual union all
select 'A2' PLANT, '2' CUSTOMERID, date'2016-01-02' CALDAY from dual union all
select 'A1' PLANT, '1' CUSTOMERID, date'2016-01-08' CALDAY from dual union all
select 'A1' PLANT, '2' CUSTOMERID, date'2016-01-08' CALDAY from dual union all
select 'A2' PLANT, '4' CUSTOMERID, date'2016-01-08' CALDAY from dual union all
select 'A2' PLANT, '4' CUSTOMERID, date'2016-01-15' CALDAY from dual union all
select 'A1' PLANT, '4' CUSTOMERID, date'2016-01-22' CALDAY from dual)


, first_buys_plant as (
  select customerid, plant, calday from (
    select customerid, plant, calday, row_number() over (partition by customerid, plant order by calday) rn
    from dt
  ) where rn = 1
)
select plant, calweek, max(cum_num) cum_num_cust from (
  select 
    plant,
    to_char(calday, 'ww') calweek,
    count(customerid) over(partition by plant order by calday rows between unbounded preceding and current row) cum_num
  from first_buys_plant
) group by plant, calweek
order by 1,2
```